# If I install bluetooth on raspberry pi, will this mean I won't need a bluetooth wifi dongle etc

Tags: bluetooth

I just discovered you can install bluetooth on the pi.

Does this mean that when pairing devices I wouldn't need dongles and such?

I have the pi2 and 4.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which Pi you have and what do you mean by installing Bluetooth?

Comment: bluetooth install page and updated the question. https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17841464-bluetooth-installing-and-using-bluetooth-on-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: Bluetooth support is split between the hardware and the software required for Bluetooth. You don't need a dongle if the Raspberry Pi model has wireless support https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Model_comparison. So the RPi2 will need a Bluetooth dongle to add the Bluetooth hardware. The RPi4 will not need a dongle as it has the hardware already.  Linux comes with the software to use the Bluetooth hardware so as long as you have an update-to-date version of the Raspberry Pi operating system you should be good from a software perspective

Comment: mind moving your comment as an answer so I can give credit? @ukBaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth support is split between the hardware and the software required.

You don't need a dongle if the Raspberry Pi model has wireless support https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Model_comparison.

For the versions you specify in your question,  the Raspberry Pi 2 will need a Bluetooth dongle to add the Bluetooth hardware.

The Raspberry Pi 4 will not need a dongle as it has the hardware already.

The Linux operating system comes with the software to use the Bluetooth hardware. If you have an update-to-date version of the Raspberry Pi operating system then you should not need anything additional.